# Can't connect to a Hyper-V VM from anywhere but the host OS

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, tcpip

I have an unusual situation on hand where I'm able to connect to a Hyper-V guest VM from the HOST, but not from anywhere but the host.

The VM is running WIn2k8R2 and has IIS installed and Remote Desktop enabled.  If I browse to the IP from the host OS, the IIS7 page displays. I can also RDP into the guest OS from the host as well as ping.

From OFF the host, RDP, web and ping all fail.  If I completely shut off the guest VM's firewall, ping will then start to respond, but all RDP and port 80 still don't.

The physical host machine has 2 nics installed, but only one is plugged in.  The one plugged in has a static IP. I have one Hyper-V virtual network and it's set to external.  The guest VM has one NIC with a different static IP than the host, but both are on the same subnet.  The host machine is joined to the domain, the guest VM is not.

Any sugestions?
Thanks so much for any help you may be able to provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, it ended up being a network firewall issue.  Nothing related to Hyper-V or the Windows firewall - or anything that was under my control really.  Chalking this one up to unfamiliarity with the environment I was working in!

Answer (score 0):

I had similliar problem a while ago.
You would need to actually port forward the ports to the VM (if accessing from the internet), if the other static IP is routed to main one.

Comment: I don't understand "if the other static IP is routed to main one."  I'm not attempt to connect to the VM from an outside network, but from a different subnet on the same corporate network.